# Profit Maximization Problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Find the  **maximum profit**  corresponding to a $\ \text{demand} \ \text{function} \ $ of $ \ p=36-4x$ and a total $\text{cost} \ \text{function} \ = 2x^2+6$

Hello. Can you kindly help me solve this problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: Gross income is $px$, which is $x(36-4x)$. So profit is $x(36-4x)-(2x^2+6)$, a quadratic. Maximize.

Answer (score 1):

Profit = Income - Costs.

I assume $x$ is the price per unit and p the number of units sold. That means Income is the number of units sold times the price per unit:

$$\text{Profit} =  (36-4x)\times x - (2x^2+6) $$

So the profit function is a quadratic expression and therefor has a turning point (vertex) as a graph, which represents the maximum value. This occurs when the gradient is 0, and the derivative is a formula for the gradient. So by making $\frac{d\text{(Profit)}}{dx}=0$ and solving x, that will give me at what price I will have a maximum profit. Substituting into Profit will give the maximum profit.

NOTE: Of course any other method of finding the vertex of a parabola should produce the same answer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for giving me and idea @Pieter.

Comment: an** idea. Anyways, I believe I already got 3 as the answer. P(x) = 36x-6x^2-6x so taking the derivative I got, P'(x)=36-12x . I equated it to zero to solve for x so I got "3" as the answer.

Comment: Its a pleasure. I have not solved the problem, but remember if you solve the derivative equal to zero, you get an answer for x. Remember we assumed x is the price per unit. So we calculated the price to charge per unit to get a maximum profit. We must still calculate what the profit will be when x=3, In other words we have the symmetry axis for the parabola, we now what the actual y-value which is the maximum. The symmetry axis is just WHERE we will have the maximum, its not the maximum itself :)